Icon of phone with three lines in call log on iPhone
There's an icon next to only one of my contacts. It's a phone over three lines. It's to the left of his name in my recent call log screen. What is it, and why is it only next to this one persons name?

It signifies the entry is for an outbound call rather than an incoming call.
